# Can someone help me understand the intuition with the formula for finding the kth Percentile?

Tags: statistics

My textbook just gave the formula without any explanation, here's the text:

If you were to do a little research, you would find several formulas for calculating the kth percentile. Here is one of them.

k = the kth percentile. It may or may not be part of the data.

i = the index (ranking or position of a data value)

n = the total number of data
• Order the data from smallest to largest.

• Calculate $i = \frac{k}{100}(n + 1)$

• If i is an integer, then the kth percentile is the data value in the ith position in the ordered set of data.

• If i is not an integer, then round i up and round i down to the nearest integers. Average the two data values in these two positions in the ordered data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think about the above formula would be using the basic definition of how a percentage of anything is computed. 
$$k = \frac{i}{n+1}100$$
$n+1$ is used here simply as a matter of indexing (there could be a $0^{th}$ percentile.)